# Proving logical equivalence

Tags: logic

I'm having a lot of trouble with proving this equivalence. I honestly don't know where to start and what to use to derive this. If anyone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it

[(¬Q ∧ P ) ∨ ¬Q] ⇔ [(¬Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (¬Q ∧ R)]

Comment: How are 'P' and 'R' related to each other?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the expression on the left-hand side is simply equivalent to $\neg Q$, and so is the expression on the right-hand side.

$(\neg Q \land \neg R)\lor (\neg Q\land R)\iff \neg Q\land(R\lor \neg R)\iff \neg Q\iff \neg Q\lor (\neg Q \land P)$, where the last equivalence follows from the [absorption law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsorptionLaw.html) (I'm assuming you can use this).

Comment: Which laws did you use to derive it? I can't use a truth table for this question and what I'm having trouble with is figuring out which laws are I have to use.

Comment: @Guest For the first equivalence, I used the distributive law while for the second, I used the fact that $P\land \text{ tautology}\equiv P$ (since $R\lor\neg R$ is a tautology).

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I'll give answer. I suggest you to use the "Truth Table". When the result is all true then the equivalence held. Here is my try:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  [(\sim & Q & ∧ & P) & ∨ & \sim & Q] & \Leftrightarrow
& [(\sim & Q & ∧ & \sim & R) & ∨ & (\sim & Q & ∧ & R)] \\ 
\hline
  \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm\color{red}T
& \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T \\ \hline
  \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm\color{red}T
& \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F \\ \hline
  \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T \\ \hline
  \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F \\ \hline
  \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T \\ \hline
  \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F \\ \hline
  \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T \\ \hline
  \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm\color{red}T 
& \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm T & \rm T & \rm F & \rm F & \rm F \\ \hline
\end{array} \\ \quad \\ 
\begin{align}   [(\sim  Q  ∧  P)  ∨  \sim  Q] & \Leftrightarrow
 [(\sim  Q  ∧  \sim  R)  ∨  (\sim  Q  ∧  R)] \\ 
[(\neg Q∧P)∨  \neg Q]&\Leftrightarrow [(\neg Q∧\neg R)∨(\neg Q∧ R)]
\end{align}$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

How about using a truth table?

You go through the four possibilities

1. $P$ and $Q$ are both true
2. $P$ is true and $Q$ is false
3. $P$ is false and $Q$ is true
4. $P$ and $Q$ are both true

This will prove the equivalence, as required.

For instance, for 1. (both are true), you get

[(¬Q ∧ P ) ∨ ¬Q] ⇔ [(¬Q ∧ ¬R) ∨ (¬Q ∧ R)]

[(¬t ∧ t ) ∨ ¬t] ⇔ [(¬t ∧ ¬t) ∨ (¬t ∧ t)]

[f ∨ f] ⇔ [(f) ∨ (f)]

f ⇔ f,
as required.